# Get username via greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, php, greasemonkey

I created a script with Greasemonkey and I want to get the username variable from a website stored on a txt file on my website ONLY once. (without saving the same name; more like... if the name exists in the txt file, don't save it again)

The site has the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="bbthing">
            <h2>Hello, <a class="notranslate" href="http://www.somewebsite.net/etc">TheUsername</a></h2>   
</div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Share your script also here..!

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear without your script. I assume you want to know how to retrieve the username? Something like `document.querySelector('.bbthing a).innerText` would work here, but it really depends on the DOM structure of the website. Or are you looking for a way to solve the 'save only once' part? Make a php script on your website, and use an AJAX POST request to submit usernames. The php script will check that it's a new one and append it to a text file.

Comment: The script has nothing implemented yet...

Answer (score 0):

Add the following resource to the metadata block:

```
// @resource custompage http://yourpage.com/downloaded_once.txt
// @grant GM_getResourceText
...
alert(GM_getResourceText("custompage"));
```